# Variables exchange between ES6 modules with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

As you know, it's possible to access to exported variables and functions of the main js-file in the module, e. g.:

**module1.js**

```
export const MODULE1_CONSTANT1 = 'Test Const From the module1.js';
```

**main.js**

```
import { MODULE1_CONSTANT1 } from './module1';
console.log(MODULE1_CONSTANT1);
```

However: is it way to access to the `main.js` variables from the `module1.js`? I suppose, the answer will be same, so is it possible to exchange by variables between modules?

I know that it's not only JavaScript matter and project build system has the influence too, so let's consider **Webpack** in this question.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but circular dependencies are frowned upon. What do you want to do?

Comment: For example, I want to store CSS selectors in the main js-file or other separate js-file (e.g. `selectors.js`). So it will be like `.ini` file: if some changes in markup, it will be enough to edit `selectors.js` without editing the logical part of the js code. Of course, the variables with selectors must be available in each module.

Comment: Yes, `selectors.js` can easily be available in every module (by simply importing it everywhere), but that does not mean it would need to access the variables of `main.js`?

Comment: I am sorry, I could not answer this question until rewrite my projects with es-6 modules. If I encounter with the case where will be attractive to get some variables or functions from the `main.js`, I write the comment here again. For now, thank you for the comments.

Comment: The answer should be "No, you don't need this". If a case comes up where you think you need it, try to rethink your module structure. If redesigning is not possible (or too complicated): no worries, you *can* import the modules into each other, you just need to make sure to only use the imported variables inside functions and not at the top level.

Comment: OK, got it! Thank you again for the explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Use keyword **require** replace keyword **import**(because **import** MUST in top of source, it is ES6 syntax), and make a function to access each module, I think it can implement variables exchange between modules.

```
// module1.js
export const MODULE1_CONSTANT1 = 'Test Const From the module1.js';
export function MAIN_CONSTANT1() {
    return require('./main').MAIN_CONSTANT1;
};


// main.js
export const MAIN_CONSTANT1 = 'Test Const From the main.js';
export function MODULE1_CONSTANT1() {
    return require('./module1').MODULE1_CONSTANT1;
};

// hello.js
import {MAIN_CONSTANT1 as main_MAIN_CONSTANT1, MODULE1_CONSTANT1 as main_MODULE1_CONSTANT1} from './main';
import {MAIN_CONSTANT1 as module1_MAIN_CONSTANT1, MODULE1_CONSTANT1 as module1_MODULE1_CONSTANT1} from './module1';

console.log('main_MAIN_CONSTANT1', main_MAIN_CONSTANT1);
console.log('main_MODULE1_CONSTANT1', main_MODULE1_CONSTANT1());
console.log('module1_MAIN_CONSTANT1', module1_MAIN_CONSTANT1());
console.log('MODULE1_CONSTANT1', module1_MODULE1_CONSTANT1);
// output
// >>> MAIN_CONSTANT1 Test Const From the main.js
// >>> MODULE1_CONSTANT1 Test Const From the module1.js
// >>> module1_MAIN_CONSTANT1 Test Const From the main.js
// >>> module1_MODULE1_CONSTANT1 Test Const From the module1.js
```

Comment: Why would you use `require` when `import` works perfectly fine?

Comment: Because when use `import` in a function, will got SyntaxError: "import" and "export" may only appear at the top level.

Comment: Well yes, you are not supposed to put the `import` inside the function declaration. Put it above and refer to the imported variable as usual.